# Capturar imagem WebView e exibir em ImageButton

Tags: android

Preciso capturar uma screenshot `webView.capturePicture` ao clique de botão e exibir em um `ImageButton`, como fazer isto?

Comment: Capturando quando clicar no botão.

Comment: Boa tarde, minha resposta lhe ajudou? Por favor me informe se tiver alguma duvida ainda. se não e a resposta lhe foi útil, por favor marque a como "correta". Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15360880/1518921), você precisará da classe `Bitmap`, `Canvas` e `BitmapDrawable`.

Um exemplo seria algo como:

```
ImageButton imageBtn;
WebView myWebView;

...

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Picture mPicture = myWebView.capturePicture();
        Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        );
        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        picture.draw(mCanvas);

        BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(mPicture);
        imageBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
    }
});
```